# The Output of High/Low Pass filters and the DB changes that occur

Tags: frequency, high-pass-filter, decibel

I recently just learned what a dB is (decibel) and am trying to figure out why in high/low pass filters these drops occur. Also how they're affected.

Say I have a high pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 60HZ. If my input voltage of 5V pk is at a frequency of 60HZ it seems my output voltage will see a 3 dB drop down to 3.535 V. How can I calculate the expected dB drop given my cutoff frequency in this case? For example say I wanted to know what frequency I need my 5V signal to come out at 2.5V (6 dB drop).

This is probably super nooby but I'd appreciate any insight on this topic you guys have to share.

EDIT: Another side thought but on-topic: I'm talking about an RC circuit above however this can also be done with an LR circuit correct? When is it advantageous to use one over the other?

Comment: Using asymptotic models, the -6dB point will be exactly 2*Fcutoff. The -20dB point will be exactly 10X. The -40dB point will be exactly 100X.

Comment: if -6dB is 2*Fcutoff then that suggests it's linear. But if that's the case shouldnt 10*Fcutoff be -30db and not -20dB? What's the relationship here?